# IIS Express does not restart in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, iis, visual-studio-2019, iis-express

In general, there is a website(`ASP .NET MVC 5`) that I run in Visual Studio.

The first time everything starts clearly, and if you restart the debug session, then the second time it does not start. If you look at the tray, then IIS Express is absent there.

Only restarting Visual Studio solves the problem, but again, only 1 time and you have to restart the studio each time.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Do you have anti-virus installed? Have you tried to disable it? And when did you start face this issue? It sounds like a compatibility issue but hard to troubleshoot. So you may have to check whehther anthing wrong with IIS express process or services.

Answer (score 0):

This happened exactly to me when I upgrade a solution from VS 2010 to VS 2017.

I searched for solutions and only found: remove the .vs directory from the solution, remove the IIS Express directory from the documents or reinstall VS.

The problem was that the solution has multiple web projects that can run. And in one of them, in the .csproj, there was this configuration:

```
<UseIISExpress>false</UseIISExpress>
<UseIIS>False</UseIIS>
```

When I set it to true, the problem was gone.

Regards.